# Playing non-Western scales on the Oud

Tags: tuning, scales, string-instruments, oud

How does one learn to play various non-Western scales on the oud? Are there instructions with diagrams showing notes as positions on the neck of the instrument? Book, videos, etc.?

Answer (score 4):

some links to pictures of Turkish and Arabic scales on neck of oud are on:

- http://www.oud.eclipse.co.uk/makamlist.html
- http://www.oud.eclipse.co.uk/maqamlist.html

some explainations of notation used are on http://www.oud.eclipse.co.uk/makamlist.html

Answer (score 1):

i3zif.com provides online lessons in English (video course) for playing the Oud. It's not free though.

http://www.i3zif.com/en/oud-english-beginners1